# "half-assed Hollywood horror"

Tags: meaning, subjunctives

*The Bye Bye Man is so bad, in fact, **that it retroactively improves the half-assed Hollywood horror that it’d be lucky to better resemble**.*

http://www.avclub.com/review/no-you-seriously-shouldnt-think-about-bye-bye-mano-248316

I am not able to understand the passage in bold from the film review. Can you explain to me why the mentioned horror movie is according to the author so bad.

Comment: pattern: **so**  +  {modifier} + **that** :   *The dinner plate was so hot that  it actually burnt my fingers*.    The quality expressed by {modifier} is possessed to such a degree, the fact expressed in the *that*-clause results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bolded passage is not saying why this movie is bad, or in what ways.  It is claiming that some really bad movies are much better than this movie.  (The other paragraphs of the review describe features of the movie that made it less enjoyable and less scary than other horror movies.)

**half-assed Hollywood horror**

Doing a "half-ass" job means not putting one's full effort into doing a job correctly.  Thus, a "half-assed" job is a job that was done poorly.

"Hollywood" refers to the United States movie-production industry.  It has a reputation for expensive, heavily promoted movies.  Some of them are excellent, but many of them are not.

In this context, a "horror" might mean a "horror movie", or "a really scary thing to think about".  A "horror movie" is a movie that people watch because they enjoy being scared (or laughing at the idea that a "cheesy horror movie" is supposed to be scary).

Sometimes people compare two hypothetical versions of something.  In one version, the thing was well made.  In the other version, the thing was poorly made.  Thinking about the difference can be scary.  The sentence "There but for the Grace of God go I" talks about this kind of difference.

**the half-assed Hollywood horror**

The definite article "the" means that the reviewer is referring to a hypothetical example of a category of things.  In this case, the category of "half-assed Hollywood horrors".

**retroactively improves**

Suppose the reviewer had rated that "half-assed Hollywood horror" back when it came out.  He might have given it 1 out of 4 stars.

The reviewer claims that this movie is so much worse than an older "half-assed Hollywood horror", that he would need to adjust the older movie's rating upward.  Suppose this movie is much worse than the older movie.  But the reviewer cannot give a movie a rating lower than 1 out of 4 stars.  If he were to rate the older movie again, he would have to give it more than 1 star just to show that it is better than the newer movie.

**that it'd be lucky to better resemble**

The reviewer is saying that this movie "would be lucky" to be more like the hypothetical "half-assed Hollywood horror", because that would make this movie better.